# Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to create a upload button in react using typescript, this is my code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function FileUploadPage(){
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);

const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setIsSelected(true);
};

const handleSubmission = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('File', selectedFile);

    fetch(
        'https://freeimage.host/api/1/upload?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        }
    )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
};
};

return(
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
        {
            isSelected ? (
            <div>
                <p>Filename: {selectedFile.name}</p>
                <p>Filetype: {selectedFile.type}</p>
                <p>Size in bytes: {selectedFile.size}</p>
                <p>
                    lastModifiedDate:{' '}
                    {selectedFile.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString()}
                </p>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <p>Select a file to show details</p>
        )}
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmission}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
) }
```

I'm getting error on this line "formData.append('File', selectedFile);". As im new to react i have no idea what this error means. This error says "Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'", i have attached the error image, Someone help me out with this error. [error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmkKv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why "Type File" dose not have "lastModifiedDate", so I use "&".

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File & { lastModifiedDate: Date }>();
// File extends Blob
formData.append('File', selectedFile as Blob);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add generic to `useState()`. Try this?

[image]

Comment: not working for me its showing the same error

Comment: Try restarting the VSCode first? If still get error, show more code for this, your code above has a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typescript error that means `selectedFile` which can be `undefined` is not assignable to `formData.append()` function which expects its second argument to have either `string` or `Blob` type (and not `undefined).

What you can do is check the validity of `selectedFile` before calling that method like this:

```
if (!selectedFile) {
  alert('Please select the file first!');
  return;
}

formData.append(...);
```

Also, `useState` needs to define the data type like this:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<string | Blob>();
```

Comment: no luck still the same error is coming while compiling

Comment: are you using `.tsx`?

Comment: yes im using .tsx

Comment: added more code. try it.